# GWT Canvas Zoom & Pan with URLs

Tags: html, gwt, canvas

I found [an answer to zooming and panning images efficiently in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284284/how-to-smoothly-zoom-a-canvas), but does anyone know how to implement a HTML canvas zoom and pan with links in GWT?

Answer (score 1):

i think this might help you. meanwhile im gonna try this as well since i also looking for it :P

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwt_hmtl5#Image_Scale_/_Resize

Comment: I found a library that does zoom and pan in GWT.  Lienzo.  I have a working prototype, but the zoom is dreadfully slow at this point.

Comment: For the record (I know this comment is long overdue), I am using Construct2 (an HTML5 canvas abstraction engine) to do my tasks now.